# How to make exe file contain VTK that can be used by other users device

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, vtk

Im build an c++ application, and this app use VTK, I generate exe file and its work nice in my local computer, but If I try to share this exe file to other user I got an error like `vtk*.dll` not found.

Note: My VTK-build is located in other directory, if its most be move with my exe, how I can configure it.

VTK ver: 8.1.1

Visual Studio: 17

Thanks

> Note: I found a none optimal solution but its work, I put all dll file
>   in current exe file location, and this resolve issue!

Comment: http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Static-Link-VTK-td5717493.html You need to build VTK with BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF

Comment: I will try that now Alex, thanks

Comment: set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} "-static") is need to set too or no?

Comment: BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF in my cmakeLists but its not work too.... its same, its work locally but not work in other device ...

Comment: Thank you @Alex F, I will check it now